# Using pretty format with rev-list

Tags: git

I want a list of commits on my feature bracnh not on the develop branch.

I'm using this following:

```
git rev-list --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ad : %s" --no-merges myFeatureBrn --not master
```

However, it is first printing out the full sha1 and then the pretty format I specified on second line like:

```
commit 7a60d895891133c858c6a71986c76a3c1de1e44e
7a60d89 - author, Mon May 26 17:19:42 2014 +0100 : Somecommit message
```

How do I get `rev-list` to just print the `pretty` format and not the big long sha1?

Comment: Not sure you can, but you can always post-process with `grep`: `git rev-list .... | grep -v '^commit '`... That might be a reasonable RFE to the `git` folks, because without `--pretty` it prints only the hash, but with `--pretty` it seems to change the format to be "commit <hash>\n<pretty-format-stuff>", which seems a bit inconsistent...

Answer (score 1):

[`git-cherry`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) can show you the commits on your feature branch that have not been merged into the develop branch.

```
$ git checkout feature-branch
$ git cherry develop
```

Or compare with upstream:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout feature-branch
$ git cherry origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

`git rev-list` is more of a scripting command, its human-friendlier cousin  is `git log`.  If you're on `myFeatureBrn` at the moment the command is

```
git log --pretty="%h - %an, %ad : %s" --no-merges master..
```

otherwise add `myFeatureBrn` after the `..`.